# Advanced Installer installkit calling .Net core method for bool value

Tags: c#, wix, advanced-installer

I have a advanced install install kit. I also have a dll and console wrapper written in .net 5 c# that gives me a bool status that I wish to use in the install kit.

I have never written a custom action before and wonder what the shortest path is to my task?

The dll method is as simple as

bool WhatIsstatus => true;

Comment: This WiX custom action sample shows the basics of using a custom action: https://github.com/glytzhkof/WiXCustomActionsTesting. If you are referring to Advanced Installer, please check their videos: https://www.youtube.com/c/advancedinstaller/search?query=custom

Comment: Thank you - that will help